# What's the Reactive way to collapse elements into an array?

Tags: json, angularjs, typescript, reactive-programming, rxjs

Take the following TypeScript/Angular 2 code sample:

```
query(): Rx.Observable<any> {

    return Observable.create((o) => {

        var refinedPosts = new Array<RefinedPost>();

        var observable = this.server.get('http://localhost/rawData.json').toRx().concatMap(
        result => 
            result.json().posts

        )
        .map((post: any) => {

            // Assume I want to convert the raw JSON data into a nice class object with 
            // methods, etc.
            var refinedPost = new RefinedPost();    
            refinedPost.Message = post.Message.toLowerCase();


            refinedPosts.push(refinedPost);
        })
        .subscribeOnCompleted(() => {
            o.onNext(refinedPosts);
        })


    });

}
```

Written out, the database is returning JSON. I want to iterate over the raw JSON and create a custom object, eventually returning to subscribers an `Array<RefinedPost>`.

The code works and the final subscribers get what they need, but I can't help but feel like I didn't do it the "Reactive Way". I cheated and used an external accumulator to gather up the elements in the Array, which seems to defeat the purpose of using streams.

So, the question is, is there a better, more concise, reactive way to write this code?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question.

```
query(): Rx.Observable<any> {

return this.server.get('http://localhost/rawData.json').toRx().concatMap(
    result =>
        result.json().posts
    )
    .map((post: any) => {
        var refinedPost = new RefinedPost();
        refinedPost.Message = post.Message.toLowerCase();

        return refinedPost;

    }).toArray();
}
```

This removes the internal accumulator and the wrapped Observable. `toArray()` took the sequence of items and brought them together into an array.

Comment: `toArray` working only for ended collection. But if you want get array of values in realtime, you can use `scan` operator.

Comment: You can also pass the function you have in `map` into `concatMap` as the second argument. you just change the function signature to `(result, post) => {}`. It will get invoked for each unrolled item from `result.json().posts`